react-hook-form `resetField` and shadcn/radix dialog
I want to display react-hook-form inside radix dialog but for some reason content is not updated properly. Here is my code
export const HomeworksBookTreeOptions = ({
  homeworksBook,
  treeRef,
}: {
  homeworksBook: HomeworkBook;
  treeRef: RefObject<TreeRef>;
}) => {
  const [dialogOpen, setDialogOpen] = useState(false);

  const {
    register,
    control,
    watch,
    resetField,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { isValid, errors },
  } = useForm<SaveHomeworksBookContentSchemaType>({
    resolver: zodResolver(saveHomeworksBookContentSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      parentId: treeRef.current?.selectedNodes?.[0]?.id.toString() || '0',
      nodeId: (
        (getLastId(treeRef.current?.treeData || []) as number) + 1
      ).toString(),
      name: '',
      homeworksBookId: homeworksBook.id,
    },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!treeRef.current?.treeData) return;
    const id = (
      (getLastId(treeRef.current?.treeData || []) as number) + 1
    ).toString();
    resetField('nodeId', {
      defaultValue: id,
    });
    resetField('parentId', {
      defaultValue: (
        treeRef.current?.selectedNodes?.[0]?.id.toString() || '0'
      ).toString(),
    });
  }, [treeRef.current?.treeData, treeRef.current?.selectedNodes, dialogOpen]);

  const mutationSaveHomeworksBookContent = useSaveHomeworksBookContent(
    homeworksBook.slug
  );

  function onSubmit(data: SaveHomeworksBookContentSchemaType) {
    mutationSaveHomeworksBookContent.mutate(data, {
      onSuccess: () => setDialogOpen(false),
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className='flex flex-col gap-1'>
      <div className='flex items-center gap-1.5 p-2'>
        <Dialog open={dialogOpen} onOpenChange={setDialogOpen}>
          <DialogTrigger asChild>
            <Button className='h-fit p-2' variant='ghost'>
              <PlusIcon />
            </Button>
          </DialogTrigger>
          <DialogContent>
            <DialogTitle>Dodaj</DialogTitle>
            <form
              className='flex flex-col gap-2'
              onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
            >
              <FormInput
                name='parentId'
                type='number'
                label='ParentId'
                errors={errors}
                register={register}
              />
              <FormInput
                name='name'
                type='text'
                label='Nazwa'
                errors={errors}
                register={register}
              />
              <FormInput
                name='nodeId'
                type='number'
                label='NodeId'
                errors={errors}
                register={register}
                disabled
              />
              <Button type='submit' disabled={!isValid}>
                Zapisz
              </Button>
            </form>
          </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
        <Button
          className='h-fit p-2'
          variant='ghost'
          onClick={() => treeRef.current?.openAll()}
        >
          <CopyPlusIcon />
        </Button>
        <Button
          className='h-fit p-2'
          variant='ghost'
          onClick={() => treeRef.current?.closeAll()}
        >
          <CopyMinusIcon />
        </Button>
        <Input
          className='w-[200px]'
          placeholder='Szukaj...'
          value={treeRef.current?.search}
          onChange={(e) => treeRef.current!.setSearch(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

In useEffect I reset form field but for some reason the dialog content is not updated even though inside useEffect the value is correct. Its udpdated but only when I open it for the second time. Any suggestions what might be the reason?
